# I have tens of millions of keys and need quickly answer whether key exists in my database or not. Which database should I use?

Tags: database, indexing, key-value

Keys are long hashes so dataset won't fit into the ram. It is not that big: 10-20Gb yet storing it in RAM is too costly for me. I have 100-1000 queries per second asking whether key exists and occasional 1-10 inserts. For a while I've been using mongo but it seems it is not up to the task since it lacks ability to control which indexes are stored into ram and which are not, so it hits hard disk quite often.

I would gladly use redis or something similar but ram is the bottleneck.

Comment: 100 million MD160 hashes takes less than 2GB. 100 million SHA256 hashes takes about 3GB. No collisions are known for either of these.

Comment: Check out [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) and [trie tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so should I use hashes of my hashes (which are quasi hashes and not the real cryptographic ones) and store them in ram?

Comment: @Moonwalker: I would use a sufficiently-strong cryptographic hash of the real value, if possible. The goal would be that all you'd need to do is compare the hash and then you'd be done. If you can do a SHA256 of the real key value, that would do. Depending on details, an MD160 of the key that's already a hash is probably fine. But you can make this all fit in RAM. (Index the RAM efficiently, of course, likely using a hash-based set like Boost's `unordered_set`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash your keys and put them into either a relational table or into a hash-table. That is the easiest solution. Next would be the use of Bloom filters which would be able to sort 99% or even more of the accesses out (in case the key is *not* present - in case it is there you don't gain anything because it could be a false positive).

Not sure why your hashes are that long. What hashing technique are you using? You might want to switch to something like SHA-160 which has a small output yet is (almost) cryptographically secure.